Poisson random variable from exponential sampling
Suppose I have exponential variables with parameter $1$: $e_i\sim Exp(1), i>1$.
How to prove that $N=\max_{p}\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^p e_i \leq \lambda\right\}$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$?
I know that $\sum_{i=1}^p e_i \sim \Gamma(p,1)$, but I guess it won't help.
Thank you.

This question is similar to: Transforming sum of n exponential distribution to a Poisson distribution. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just note that for $p\in \mathbb{N}$ we have ${N\geq p}={\sum_{k\leq p}e_k\leq \lambda}$ so $P(N\geq p)=\frac{1}{(p-1)!}\int_0^\lambda x^{p-1}e^{-x}dx$ and so $P(N<p)=\frac{\Gamma(p,\lambda)}{(p-1)!}$ where $\Gamma(x,y)$ is the upper incomplete Gamma function. This is the Poisson distribution.

How did you get the expression for $P(N\geq p)$? What is ${N\geq p}$? Is it $P(N\geq p)$?

It indicates an event (a measurable set). Don't worry about it, write it within $P$ if you prefer.

How did you get the expression involving integral for $P(N\geq p)$?

Since $P(N\geq p)=P(\sum_{k\leq p}e_k\leq \lambda)$, use the Gamma distribution of $\sum_{k\leq p}e_k$

One way to proceed, based on your initial observations, is to notice that $N\ge p$ if and only f $S_p\le \lambda$, where $S_p:=\sum_{i=1}^p e_i$.
Because $S_p$ has that gamma distribution,
$$
P[N\ge p]=\int_0^\lambda {e^{-x}x^{p-1}\over\Gamma(p)}\,dx,\qquad p=1,2,\ldots.
$$
Clearly $P[N\ge 0]=1$. Subtracting,
$$
P[N=p]=\int_0^\lambda e^{-x}\left({x^{p-1}\over (p-1)!}-{x^p\over p!}\right)\,dx={1\over p!}\int_0^\lambda e^{-x}\left({px^{p-1}}-{x^p}\right)\,dx,
$$
for $p=0,1,2,\ldots$.
To integrate this just notice that $e^{-x}(px^{p-1}-x^p)={d\over dx}e^{-x}x^p$.

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. exponential(1) random variables (inter-arrival times).
Set $N(t)=0$ for $t<Y_1$; $N(t)=1$ for $Y_1\le t<Y_1+Y_2$ etc., then
$$
N(t)=\max\{p:\ Y_1+Y_2+...Y_p<t\}
$$
is a classical Poisson process with rate $1$. Hence $N(t)\sim Poi(t\cdot 1)$.

Can you provide a rigorous proof?
